# After installing bumblebee, overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir' with black screen

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, nvidia, bumblebee

I was trying resolve an issue with my nvidia/intel GPUs in my laptop. Installed bumblebee, bumblebee-nvidia, and primus, and I added my username to the bumblebee group, then ran ‘optirun glxgears -info’. I rebooted my computer, and I now receive the following error:

```
aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[1089]: no arg
overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
```

I tried using prime-select to switch to nvidia and intel, but I am stuck at a blank screen with intel, and with nvidia, I am stuck at the login screen on an external monitor, but I can’t type or see the mouse.

I have no idea what is happening. I tried reinstalling the nvidia drivers, and I removed bumblebee, bumblebee-nvidia, and primes, but still no luck.

Note: the missing lower dir error flashes on my laptop screen before showing a blinking cursor. Sometimes the error doesn’t show, and I only see the cursor. Also, I couldn’t see the error long enough to see the number in brackets, so the number may be incorrect. I think in changed between attempts to boot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 18.04 on the system that has this error?

Comment: @matigo Yes, I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with 5.4 kernel